# Navit Excepition:java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: android, navit

While running the Navit code for car navigation, I am getting the following exception, i thought that navit library is not available. please any one help me.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(  365): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
E/AndroidRuntime(  365): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
E/AndroidRuntime(  365):        at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  365):        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1472)
E/AndroidRuntime(  365):        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1097)
E/AndroidRuntime(  365):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
E/AndroidRuntime(  365):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
E/AndroidRuntime(  365):        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:116)
E/AndroidRuntime(  365):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
E/AndroidRuntime(  365):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(  365):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(  365):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
E/AndroidRuntime(  365):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  365):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime(  365):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
E/AndroidRuntime(  365):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
E/AndroidRuntime(  365):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  365): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library navit not found
E/AndroidRuntime(  365):        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:489)
E/AndroidRuntime(  365):        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:557)
```

i downloaded the Navit code from , navit svn.ttps://navit.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/navit/trunk/navit  But unable to run the code.

i want to run this code in Eclipse for Android Project.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to download Android NDK
2. Create standalong tools for your ARCH
3. Cross compile to ARM
4. Run make apkg

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to missing `libnavit.so`.

1. Put libnavit.so it in `/data/local`
2. Change System.LoadLibrary to `System.Load("/data/local/libnavit.so");`
3. `make apkg`
4. Install
5. This exception should go away.